# AngularJS - Controller JavaScript $http.get

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following code to get info from a JSON.

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/folder/'Id)
     .success(function (response) {
           console.log("response ", response);
           console.log("words: ", response.result.all.Word);
     })
     .error(function (response) {
           console.log("error");
     });
```

But I have a problem to get info in the array:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined
```

In **response** I have:

```
response  [Object, Object]
  0: Object
    _id: "543e95d78drjfn38ed53ec"
     result: Object
       all: ObjectWord: Array[17]
        0: "word1"
        1: "word2"
        2: "word3"
         ...
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: response is an array of objects. According to the JSON result object is inside the first array. Try adding an index response[0].result.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `response` appears to be an array of 2 objects.

Replace:

```
console.log("words: ", response.result.all.Word);
```

With:

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
    console.log("words: ", response[i].result.all.Word);
}
```

This should iterate over both objects in the response, and log the related word.

Comment: Thanks but still have an error "words:  undefined" . I have also to iterate with "Words"?

Comment: That means that `response[i].result.all` does not have a property called `Word`. Try `console.log("words: ", response[i].result.all);` to see what it _does_ contain.

Comment: @Carlos i think it's `response[i].result.all[0]`

Comment: @Carlos was dat for me

Comment: Now what does dat mean @Carlos ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing index, try the below code:

```
response[i].result.all[j]   where j=0....n
```

Comment: U r not txtng. Please don't write like that.